# Stateless or bound-once components in Angular2 / Angular4?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-components

Lets say I need to output an icon, based on some numeric value. For example: 1 - red icon, 2 - blue icon, 3 - green icon, etc. I want to have only presentation and do not need to store the state for any use, also state of the icon (or the numeric value) will not change.

I wonder what is the best way to achieve such presentation output?

Currently I use a pipe:

```
<div [innerHtml]="1 | numberToIcon"></div>
```

Such syntax is hard to remember. So I would like to replace it with a component:

```
<my-icon value="1" />
```

But I am worried that using the component will make Angular track component's state. And I do not want to waste memory for it.

Is there any "light" components way? Maybe components without a state?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@Component({
  ...,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class MyIconComponent {
  constructor(this.cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    cdRef.detach();
  }
}
```

`OnPush` causes change detection only to happen when an input changes or an even handler was called or when explicitly called.
If you detach the change detector, then Angular shouldn't do any change detection for this component anymore.